`urdf2webots` Converter is producing wrong results
To convert my URDF to a PROTO I ran: ros2 run xacro xacro path/to/in/file | python3 -m urdf2webots.importer --output=path/to/out/file, but I end up with some weird results:

The robot with the red box attached is visualized in RViz directly from the URDF. The robot with the gray box is the one in Webots. Clearly the box doesn't have the right orientation. With a different, but related, robot I have had another strange thing happen where the tf tree appears to be shifted:

Here, the tf's for the rail and pedistal look good, but for some reason the base_link of the robot is shifted horizontally (height seems to be okay). This "shifted" tf tree only happens when webots is in charge of publishing the tree: when launching the included view_cell.launch of this robot, RViz shows the tree as I would expect it to be.
I can post the PROTO's and URDFs on request, but since RViz has no issues with the URDFs and I used to urdf2webots converter to get the PROTO's I'm (biased) to think the problem might be in the urdf2webots converter itself.
Any suggestions or info would be welcom!! Thanks :)
